# sp giving output but SqlDataReader not

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SP in C# project to retrieve the output using SqlDataReader.
Below is the code.

```
 public List<LMTUsage> GetCompanyID(string userID, int roleId, String Organisation, String BusinessArea)
    {
        List<LMTUsage> objLMT = new List<LMTUsage>();
        LMTUsage _oELMTUsage;

        SqlConnection oCon = new SqlConnection(ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["LMTConnectionString"].ConnectionString);
        oCon.Open();

        try
        {
            using (SqlCommand _oCmd = new SqlCommand())
            {
                _oCmd.Connection = oCon;

                _oCmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
                _oCmd.CommandText = "[SC_GetDropdownValues]";

                _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@UserId", userID));
                _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@RoleId", roleId));

                if (Organisation == "")
                    _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Organisation", DBNull.Value));
                else
                    _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Organisation", Organisation));

                if (BusinessArea == "")
                    _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BusinessArea", DBNull.Value));
                else
                    _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@BusinessArea", BusinessArea));

                _oCmd.Parameters.Add(new SqlParameter("@Type", 3));


                using (SqlDataReader _oRdr = _oCmd.ExecuteReader())
                {
                   // _oRdr.Close();
                    while (_oRdr.Read())
                    {
                        _oELMTUsage = new LMTUsage();
                        _oELMTUsage.Company = _oRdr["Company"].ToString();

                        objLMT.Add(_oELMTUsage);
                    }
                    _oRdr.Close();
                }
            }
            return objLMT;
        }
        catch (Exception Ex)
        {
            throw Ex;
        }
        //finally
        //{
        //    oCon.Close();
        //    oCon.Dispose();
        //}
    }
```

It is very Simple SP with the select statement.
SP return the output when executed from SQL 2014 but when implemented in the above method it doesn't return any output.
Below is the screen for reference.
[image: Screen shot]

Please guide.

Comment: Are you sure the connection string points to the correct database server you are running the procedure on SSMS and getting results from?

Comment: Also, are you sure you are using the same parameters as when the SP ran? What does _oCmd.Parameters contain right before you ExecuteReader?

Comment: @RigertaDemiri Yes. Connection is pointing to correct DB

Comment: @DancingFool Yes Same number of parameter SP and in Method.

Comment: pankaj, sorry, I did not mean the same number of parameters. I meant are you sure the values in those parameters are the same as the values you tested your stored procedure with. If they have been corrupted somewhere before this point, that could explain the results you are (not) getting.

Comment: @DancingFool Yes. Values are same.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your stored procedure is specifically named [SC_GetDropdownValues] (including the square brackets), you don't need to define square brackets in your SqlCommand's `CommandText`. Try:

```
_oCmd.CommandText = "SC_GetDropdownValues";
```

Answer (score 0):

Please check values in parameters. 
And use Dataset with fill method to retrive data from sp instead of using ExecuteReader().

Comment: Hey there! You should [edit] your answer to include a bit more context as to *why* they should use a Dataset instead of `ExecuteReader`. As far as I'm personally concerned, `ExecuteReader` is perfectly acceptable.