# SP returning output but SqlDataReader/SqlDataAdapter not

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using SP in C# project to retrieve the output using SqlDataReader. Below is the code.

[image]

It is very Simple SP with the select statement. SP return the output when executed from SQL 2014 but when implemented in the above method it doesn't return any output. 
Both of them has same parameters and DB pointing to the correct server and DB Below is the screen for reference.

[image: Screen shot of SP]
It is returning count 43. But in the code it is empty.

Kindly help.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SQL OUTPUT Stored Procedures not working with ExecuteReader](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6374193/sql-output-stored-procedures-not-working-with-executereader)

Comment: Please edit your question and post the source code as text. Please NEVER post source code in images. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: [You already asked this same question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51167794/sp-giving-output-but-sqldatareader-not). Please don't do that as it causes duplicate effort for all parties involved.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `SqlDataReader` instead of `SqlDataAdapter`?

```
using(SqlDataReader reader = _oCmd.ExecuteReader())
{
    DataTable dataTable = new DataTable();
    dataTable.Load(reader);

    objLMT = ConvertTo<LMTUsage>(dataTable);
}
```